Selective sync using lftp or ncftp
folder_root
    folder1
        folder1.1
                folder1.1.2
                folder_R5
                    data1.zip
                    info.txt
                    abc.laz
        folder2
        folder3
        folder_R41
            anything.any
            somefile.jpg
            someotherfile.png
    folder4
        folder4.1
            folderR51
            README

I have a folder structure on a remote ftp-server with multiple folders. How can I sync or mirror the whole directory structure to my computer but mirroring only the folders that match ”r5*”, ”R5*”, ”s4*” ”S4*” in their name. I want to download everything in those directories and their subdirectories.
I wish to have these in sync but only selectively:
Remote:
ftp://$HOSTNAME/rootfolder/folder_root/
Local:
$localhost/home/myname/storage/folder_root/
How do I do that with lftp or ncftp?
#!/bin/bash

# Server details
FTP_SERVER="ftp://example.name/"
REMOTE_PATH="/demofolder/"
LOCAL_PATH="$HOME/Downloads/demofolder" # Make sure to use an existing local path

# Ensure the local directory exists
mkdir -p "${LOCAL_PATH}"

# Start lftp session
lftp -u anonymous, -e "
open ${FTP_SERVER}
lcd ${LOCAL_PATH}
cd ${REMOTE_PATH}
cls -1
bye
" | grep -E '^(R4|R5)' > /tmp/dirlist.txt

# Check if /tmp/dirlist.txt is not empty or does not exist
if [ ! -s /tmp/dirlist.txt ]; then
  echo "No directories starting with R4 or R5 found in /orto/"
  exit 0
fi

# Read the file and mirror each directory
while IFS= read -r dir; do
  echo "Mirroring ${dir}"
  lftp -u anonymous, -e "
  open ${FTP_SERVER}
  lcd ${LOCAL_PATH}
  mirror --verbose \"${dir}\" \"${LOCAL_PATH}/${dir}\"
  bye
  "
done < /tmp/dirlist.txt

# Clean up the temporary file
rm /tmp/dirlist.txt


